# Десериализовать JSON response

Tags: java, json, gson

получаю некую информацию из апи, ответ приходит в виде JSON (Слишком большой , будет нечитабельно здесь, доступен по ссылке https://app.quicktype.io?share=3Q1ydLTOJI9rgcoUyW6d).
Из всего ответа мне необходим только один объект -

```
"13.0.0": {
      "days": {
        "0": {
          "1380": 1,
          "420": 0
        }
      },
      "seasons": {
        "101": 0
      },
      "weeks": {
        "0": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
```

Сделал для него такую модель:

```
public class Days {
    @SerializedName("days")
    @Expose
    private Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Integer>> days;

    public Days(){
    }
    public Days(Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Integer>> days){
        super();
        this.days = days;
    }
    public Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Integer>> getDays(){
        return this.days;
    }
    public void setDays(Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Integer>> days){
        this.days = days;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return days.toString();
    }
```

Также два таких же класс для Seasons и Weeks. И общий класс:

```
public class Tariff {
    @SerializedName("13.0.0")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tariffList;
    @SerializedName("days")
    @Expose
    private Days days;
    @SerializedName("seasons")
    @Expose
    private Seasons seasons;
    @SerializedName("weeks")
    @Expose
    private Weeks weeks;

    public Tariff(){
    }
    public Tariff(List<Object> tariffList,Days days, Seasons seasons, Weeks weeks){
        super();
        this.tariffList = tariffList;
        this.days = days;
        this.seasons = seasons;
        this.weeks = weeks;
    }
    public List<Object> getTariffList(){
        return this.tariffList;
    }
    public Days getDays(){
        return this.days;
    }
    public Seasons getSeasons(){
        return this.seasons;
    }
    public Weeks getWeeks(){
        return this.weeks;
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь парсить подобным образом:

```
    public Tariff parseTariffByModemId(String responseBody){
        JsonObject object = JsonParser.parseString(responseBody).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("13.0.0");
        return new Gson().fromJson(object, Tariff.class);
    }
```

Но на выходе получаю NPE и понимаю что ответ маппится неправильно. Где конкретно ошибка не могу понять
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Где именно вы получаете NPE? Скорее всего дело в явно неправильном типе переменной: `private List<Object> tariffList`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб при вызове метода parseTariffByModemId.
Например вот так:
`Tariff tariff = parser.parseTariffByModemId(getTariff.execute(modemId),modemId)`
Все поля являются null. При это метод getTariff возвращает значение 100%

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ![Скрин](https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/12/24/238df1977aa54c036c8118f7c4abca2d-full.png)

Comment: Скрин посмотреть не могу - не хожу по ссылкам на неизвестные сайты.

Comment: У вас неправильная модель. В вашем классе Tariff  должно быть одно поле - например `@SerializedName("13.0.0") Tariff2 tarif`. А вот в классе Tariff2 должны быть все остальные поля класса Tariff  за исключением `tariffList`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб убрал `List<Object>`, разделил на два класса с полями Days, Weeks и Seasons в одном с названием Details, и с `@SerializedName("13.0.0") Details details` в другом. Тем не менее NPE остается на своем месте.
За ссылку на скриншот прощу прощения, неправильно с моей стороны.

Comment: Должно работать. Возможно, вы не тот JSON, который у вас есть показываете? В данный момент в вопросе вообще не JSON у вас. Нет ни квадратных ни фигурных скобок в начале/конце.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб возвращается JSON на примерно 150 строк, один из объектов которого "13.0.0". Сам JSON вида `{ "Integer" : { //некоторые значения, "13.0.0": { "days": { "0": {"1380": 1, "420": 0}, "1":{"0":"1"}}, "seasons":{"101":0}, "weeks": {"0":[0,0,0]}}, //другие объекты}}` .Объект "13.0.0" получаю вот так `JsonParser.parseString(responseBody).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject(Integer).getAsJsonObject("13.0.0")` Предполагаю, что модель неправильная на уровне Days, Seasons и Weeks, где использую `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>`

Comment: Вы меня совсем запутали. У вас в вопросе один код, а в комментах другой. Если JSON как вы в комменте написали, то код из вопрос выведет, понятно, null - `JsonParser.parseString(responseBody).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("13.0.0");`. А тот, что в комменте `.getAsJsonObject(Integer)` - не скомпилируется. Наверное, вам надо в кавычки взять `.getAsJsonObject("Integer")`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб под Integer понимается не конкретно Integer, а любое числовое значение, оно там динамическое. Сами доступы к объектам JSON корректные, при дебаге они не null. Объект передаваемый `Gson().fromJson(object, Tariff.class)` соответствует структуре, которая показана в вопросе.

Comment: Всё же думаю, что проблема в Integer - за долгие годы практики не встречал ничего такого. ПОпробуйте вот на этом сайте получить классы из JSON: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/